# Input mask jquery : letter or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [jquery input mask](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/index.html),
We can specify number and letter. How to get the format where user can input letter or number,

A = Letter,
9 = number.

I need a mask like this `AA - (A or 9)(A  or 9) - 99`,

For example, it can be `AA-99-99`

and in another case it can be `AA-A9-99`, or

`AA-AA-99`,

and so on. I have tried a lot, not suitable.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

As you noted `*` stands for alphanumeric character, so `AA-**-99` should do the job.

Or you could use regexp lik `[A-Za-z]{2}-\w{2}-\d{2}`, but it looks like regex placeholders like `\w` are not supported like this. Enclosing it to square brackets works ok:

```
<input id="example2" data-inputmask-regex="[A-Za-z]{2}-[\w]{2}-\d{2}" />
```

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SDkFm5VChO7W19VuOXmK?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), you can use this method.
The regex `AA-([A]|[9])([A]|[9])-99` will match your situation of numbers/letters.

HTML

```
<input id="example2" data-inputmask-regex="AA-([A]|[9])([A]|[9])-99" />
```

Javascript

```
(function() {

    $("#example2").inputmask();

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If by A you mean exactly the letter A and by 9 exactly the number 9, then this should work for you:

```
$("#myinput").inputmask({mask:"[AA]-[A|9]{2}-[99]"});
```